# Resize the sidebar (prototype cells)

Tags: size, prototype, cells

As a Xcode beginner I want to know how to change the width of the sidebar. In the viewcontroller I have a few prototype cells in which I've a label and a image, but because they don't take so much space, I have a empty space, which I want to get rid of.

Can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask